# Why can I stop a Sound in a Screen's hide event but am I unable to pause it? LIBGDX

Tags: java, audio, android-activity, libgdx

I'm using LIBGDX for my gamedev. I'm using com.badglogic.gdx.audio.Sound for my game sounds. I have a weird problem in my game screen . If I press the HOME button of my phone to exit the game and I **Sound.stop** the sound in the hide event of the game screen then when I re-enter the game I don't hear the sound anymore and that is what is supposed to happen. But if I instead use the **Sound.pause** method (instead of stop) then I hear the sound when I re-enter the game instance.

Why does **Sound.stop** work and **Sound.pause** doesn't?

PS: I've removed all the **Sound.resume** method instances from my code that would possible create such behavior.

works:

```
@Override
public void hide(){
    spaceship_sound.stop(id_spaceship_sound);
}
```

doesn't work:

```
@Override
public void hide(){
    spaceship_sound.pause(id_spaceship_sound);
}
```

I've even put the pause method in the keyDown (HOME button) and pause game screen events, practically all over the code with no luck.